# Get remaining part of the url (including slashes) in Falcon

Tags: python, falconframework

In my [Falcon](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) app I would like to register a route like this:

```
app.add_route("/more_details/{some_id}", handler)
```

The problem is, that the part of `some_id` might contain an arbitrary number of slashes. So the url might be `/more_details/123/456` or `/more_details/12/34/56/78` or just `/more_details/1234`. I would like to get `123/456`, `12/34/56/78` and `1234` as `some_id`. Is that possible at all in Falcon? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to access the url detail in the view handling the request (`handler`) you can use either [the uri or url](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/request_and_response.html#falcon.Request.uri) attribute of the request argument in the method for the handler. Obviously you would need to do your own processing in the view to get the information you need from the url.